# How to deploy PHP web site as a package on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, deployment, package

If my question has already taken place in other post, please excuse me.

I am coding a `PHP` - `MySQL` website and publishing it on IIS.
The way that enables me to do this is enabling CGI extension of `IIS` and copying the source `PHP` files to a folder under the "inetpub" folder.

Here is the question. If i DON'T want to copy my `PHP` files (which are including my codes obviously) into "inetpub" folder, is there a way to make a package file of my `PHP` files? For example a `Tomcat` server executes ".war" package files. Is there a package file type that i can put my `PHP` pages in it and deploy it on IIS and publish it on IIS?

If there is no way to achieve this, what can i do to prevent copyng and pasting the `PHP` files into "inetpub" folders?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at Web Deploy. It doesn't package the files as compactly as WAR but it's the "official way":

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy